# Why does my for-loop not loop through my table cells? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a table and want to iterate through each cell when the button, which the cell contains, is clicked. However, the loop just doesn't seem to run and I can't find the problem.

here is the code snippet :

```js
    element.onclick = function() {

        //Sets color of selected element
       for (var i = 0, cell; cell = document.getElementById('targetLocation').row.cells[i]; i++) {

            if (cell.firstChild.style.background == "rgba(223, 22, 22, 0.53)") {
                    
                cell.firstChild.style.background = 'red';
            }

            else {
                alert('Despite all, I loop')
            };
        };
    };
```

```html
<table id="targetLocation">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>H</th>
            <th>I</th>
            <th>J</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here's the relevant JavaScript:

For clarification: "element" is the element which you're hovering over. When hovering over a cell, the background color turns to rgba(223, 22, 22, 0.53). If you're currently hovering over that cell and you click that button, it's supposed to turn red. The onclick-function itself works, if I set an alert in that function, for example, it works so I'm guessing it's the for-loop that's broken.

Comment: Can you post a working snippet?

Comment: What is `row` supposed to be? There's only [`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows).

Comment: @PeterMader thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

[`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)s don't have a `row` property. If you want to select a row element by a specific index, use the [`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection):

```
document.getElementById('targetLocation').rows[1].cells[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i have corrected your syntex , take this advice slice down you code to part 
to identifying errors , what i did was get all `tr` then get all `td` from second tr then loop them

```js
document.getElementById('targetLocation').onclick = function() {
trtable = document.getElementById('targetLocation').getElementsByTagName('tr')[1];
tcells = trtable.getElementsByTagName("td");
cellcount = tcells.length;
        //Sets color of selected element
       for (var i = 0;i< cellcount; i++) {
  cell = tcells[i];
            if (cell.firstChild.style.background == "rgba(223, 22, 22, 0.53)") {
                    
                cell.firstChild.style.background = 'red';
                console.log('but this time, I found color on cell :'+i);
            }

            else {
                console.log('Despite all, I loop');
            }
        }
    };
    
function getTarget(elem)
{

}
```

```html
<table id="targetLocation">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>H</th>
            <th>I</th>
            <th>J</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)" style="background:rgba(223, 22, 22, 0.53);">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to hard code the style attribute in a tag element.

Use CSS class instead.

Also, you make a condition on a property (color) that could be changed in the future. It's prone to error. Don't ever do that.

Use CSS class instead.

Your code could become:

```js
document.getElementById('targetLocation').onclick = function() {
trtable = document.getElementById('targetLocation').getElementsByTagName('tr')[1];
tcells = trtable.getElementsByTagName("td");
cellcount = tcells.length;

//Sets color of selected element
for (var i = 0 ; i< cellcount; ++i ) {
  cell = tcells[i];

  // Condition is against class only, aspect can change
  // => good practice

  if (cell.firstChild.className.indexOf("selected") > -1 ) {
          
    // Here you should use CSS class too
    // What if your designer wants to apply a more beautifull color?
    // cell.firstChild.style.background = 'red';
    // So:
    cell.firstChild.className = 'someRed';

    console.log('but this time, I found color on cell :'+i);
  }

    else {
        console.log('Despite all, I loop');
    }
}
};
    
function getTarget(elem){}
```

```css
button.selected {
  background:rgba(223, 22, 22, 0.53);
}

.someRed {
  background-color: red ; // or anything else
}
```

```html
<table id="targetLocation">
  <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><th>E</th><th>F</th><th>G</th><th>H</th><th>I</th><th>J</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells selected" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
    <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```